# PrintWriter flush is not working on Windows Server 2012

Tags: java, windows, flush, printwriter

I use PrintWriter  to write file with autoFlush = true:
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), autoFlush);

Without calling pw.flush(), every time I call pw.println(...), content is write to output file.

It work fine on Win7 and Win Server 2008 but not Win Server 2012.  I tried using same JDK, for Win Server 2012 env, file only flush out after pw.close() is called in finally block (e.g reach the end of program or exception happen).

According to javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#flush()

*If the intended destination of this stream is an abstraction provided by the underlying operating system, for example a file, then flushing the stream guarantees only that bytes previously written to the stream are passed to the operating system for writing; it does not guarantee that they are actually written to a physical device such as a disk drive.*

Seem like OS issue.  Any help on that?

Here the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class TestPW {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File file = null;
        PrintWriter pw = null;

        try {
            boolean autoFlush = true;

            file = new File("C:\\NotBackedUp\\test.txt");
            pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), autoFlush);

            int loop = 100000000;

            while (loop > 0) {
                pw.println("Test: " + loop);
                loop--;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (pw != null) {
                    pw.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

The workaround is close the pw after some number of loop processed and re-init the pw object again as below....

```
import java.io.*;

public class TestPSMaxLine {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File file = null;
        PrintStream ps = null;

        int maxLinesToWriteBeforeClose = 100000;

        try {
            boolean appendFile = true;
            boolean autoFlush = true;

            file = new File("C:\\NotBackedUp\\test.txt");
            ps = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(file, appendFile), autoFlush);

            int loop = 100000000;
            int lineNum = 0;

            while (loop > 0) {
                ps.println("Test: " + loop);
                loop--;
                lineNum++;
                if(lineNum % maxLinesToWriteBeforeClose ==0){
                    closeFile(ps);
                    ps = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(file, appendFile), autoFlush);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            closeFile(ps);
        }
    }

    private static void closeFile(PrintStream ps){
        try{
            if (ps != null) {
                ps.close();
            }   
        } catch (Exception e) { 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an exception, but `PrintWriter` swallows exceptions. You need to check for them manually. Or else use `BufferedWriter`, which doesn't swallow exceptions.

Comment: I tried with BufferedWriter, either I have bw.flush() after loop--; and/or specified the size of buffer in the BufferedWriter constructor, that is no exception running the program.

And the result is exactly same as using PrintWriter where the output file is remain 0 size till the program ended or terminated.

Comment: This only happen in Win Server 2012, for other env (e.g Win7, Win Server 2008) which I tested are working fine where the file size keep increasing while program running (e.g content is flush out during the loop).

Comment: Sure there was no exception? Even on `close()`? You're ignoring it in the code you posted.

Comment: Ok, after I placed the e.printStackTrace(); inside try-catch block for close(), and that is still not exception.

Comment: The problem is buffer didn't flush out in the loop even explicitly called flush() after the loop-- statement.  Where the file size remain 0 byte till the program finished or terminated.  That is no error in close(), else there will not have file generated with content.

Comment: The problem is that Windows 2012 doesn't update the file size until it is closed.

Comment: Not just didn't update the file size. While the program still running, I opened the output file with notepad and it is empty. The buffer didn't flush out until program ended or terminated. Same program run on diff env with same JDK is work fine where file size increasing and file open can see the data. Is that anything I need adjust for that windows env?

Comment: No idea, but `BufferedWriter` is the same code on all platforms, so it can't be anything to do with that.

Comment: Hello, songjing i have the some with my windows 2012 flush() method not work. but in my windows 7 working fine. the problem is that i tried write 2 millons of lines. and if flush() not working it save in memory after close() methods called and send data to file. You can resolved it?